# Why jupyter-notebook doesn't run interactive plots?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, altair

I have seen that `jupyter-lab` can show some interactive plots like [***plot.ly***](https://plot.ly/) or [***altair***](https://altair-viz.github.io/index.html), but when I plot the same code in `jupyter-notebook` there isn't any plot

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.cars()

alt.Chart(source).mark_point().encode(
   x='Horsepower',
   y='Miles_per_Gallon',
   size='Acceleration'
)
```

The output is just a ***VegaLite 2 object*** but there isn't any plot.

Why I can't use jupyter-notebook to plot interative graphs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To display altair plots in Jupyter Notebook (not JupyterLab), you need to install the [vega](https://github.com/vega/ipyvega) python package and enable the renderer by running `alt.renderers.enable('notebook')`. This is mentioned explicitly in [Altair's installation instructions](https://altair-viz.github.io/getting_started/installation.html#quick-start-altair-notebook).

There is more trouble-shooting information, including trouble-shooting for the particular output you're seeing, in [Altair's documentation](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/troubleshooting.html#notebook-vega-lite-2-object).

Answer (score 0):

Jupyter Notebook is an application that has been around for some time. It has a lot of neatness, but primarily it is a layer between you and the Python terminal. So you can write bigger/more complex code than you could easily do in the terminal with the ability to go back and make changes without having to repeat lots of other lines of code.

Jupyter Lab is a new project by the same people who developed Jupyter Notebook. Jupyter Lab is more like a minimalist IDE. While Jupyter Notebook only allows you to run  notebooks, in Lab you can run:

1. Text files (For input or for building python modules)
2. Jupyter Notebooks
3. Bash or other terminal
4. Python Terminal

You can initialize any combination of those and lay them out however you want.

So which you choose depends on your project, I find both to be extremely useful applications for one-off data manipulation or prototyping code.